# How to change SVN server IP address in client system after a checkout?

Tags: svn, netbeans, svn-server

When I checkout my project into my local system the IP address of SVN server is `192.168.5.x`.

Because I have a DHCP server in my network, now the SVN IP changes to `192.168.5.y`.

When I try to commit I get an error regarding this issue, now how can I point to the new IP? I'm using NetBeans to do SVN actions as wells in development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For netbeans IDE,in main menu select Team->Relocate their give your modified URL,[Source](http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic48254.html)

Edit: Similarly in RapidSVN,in menu Repository->switch URL option will be there,here we can give new URL of SVN repository and check the relocate option.

Answer (score 3):

The command you want is svn switch. You can read more about its syntax by investigating svn help switch, but briefly;

```
svn switch --relocate <OLD REPOSITORY LOCATION> <NEW REPOSITORY LOCATION>
```

Be careful. Double check your addresses and make sure it doesn't get interrupted half-way through (especially if you're using SVN 1.6) or you'll have to clean up the mess afterwards.

Edit: Afterthought. Your SVN server should really have a static DHCP IP address, otherwise you'll have to keep switching this. Or at least a dynamic hostname which constantly points to the right IP address. It'll make your life easier.

Comment: Thanks for your response,I'm using UberSVN in Ubuntu,can you have idea's on UberSVN ?

Comment: Having never used it, I don't have much of an insight into it. I can't imagine why the process would be any different, but I think you should read UberSVN's documentation to verify that it isn't. I would start with [this page](http://docs.ubersvn.com/v1.0/reference.html#R73)

Comment: I'm glad someone posted the actual svn code to get it working, not the gui click stuff, thanks, have an upvote. Note that if you get the full path wrong, svn will let you know what it needs to look like on the failure error, the location is the full path svn used, like say: svn+ssh://[ip address]/your/repo/path

Answer (score 1):

In Tortoise SVN Client,

Go to root folder of the svn project. Then, right click.

TortoiseSVN->Relocate. And assign the new IP address.

Done

Answer (score 1):

In NetBeans 8.0.2 :

- Disconnect the repository (Menu: Team->Disconnect)
- Clear repository url history (Menu: Tools->Options->Team->Subversion->Manage Connections Settings)
- Reconnect with new url (Menu: Team->Connect)